# Access Aggregated Values in Group By Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with values such as:

```
name    action           time
------------------------------
Sam     enters building  20:00
Chris   enters building  20:15
Sam     walks up stairs  20:20
Steve   leaves building  20:25
James   enters building  20:30
Chris   takes elevator   20:32
Sam     leaves building  20:35
Chris   leaves building  20:40
Sam     enters building  20:45
...
```

I want to get the counts of distinct actions, per person. This I am able to accomplish with `df.groupby(['name','action'], as_index=False).size()`

However, this gives me a visual, which I can't do much with. I would like to use these counts for different purposes. How can I put this data into an accessible data frame, so that I can get things like the amount of times each person entered and left the building. For example, I could call  like `df['name' == 'Sam' & 'action'=='enters building]` and assign that count to a variable?

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1):

To make it a dataframe, you can use `.reset_index()` and then set it to df.

```
df=df.groupby(['name','action'], as_index=False).size().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `count` instead - `size` is not aggregating function in `pandas` that's why your command `as_index=False` doesn't do anything.

```py
df.groupby(['name','action'], as_index=False).count()
```

Outputs:

```py
    name           action  time
0  Chris  enters building     1
1  Chris  leaves building     1
2  Chris   takes elevator     1
3  James  enters building     1
4    Sam  enters building     2
5    Sam  leaves building     1
6    Sam  walks up stairs     1
7  Steve  leaves building     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your initial idea.
In this case you obtain a Pandas series. You can directly index the values in which you are interested.

```
table = df.groupby(['name','action'], as_index=False).size()
table['Sam']['enters building']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution where you add the `size` so you can still work with the original dataframe:

```
df['size'] = df.groupby(['name', 'action']).transform(np.size)
df.iloc[[0,2,-1], :]


#   name  action            time    size
# 0 Sam   enters building   20:00   2
# 2 Sam   walks up stairs   20:20   1
# 8 Sam   enters building   20:45   2
```